# Move rows from TableA into Table-Archive

Tags: mysql, archive

Is it possible to move rows that are 3 days old into an other table called "Table_Archive" automatically in mysql ones a week?

tableA ex:

```
ID | stringvalue | Timestamp
1  | abc         | 2011-10-01
2  | abc2        | 2011-10-02
3  | abc3        | 2011-10-05
4  | abc4        | 2011-10-10
5  | abc5        | 2011-10-11
```

**After the move**

tableA:

```
ID | stringvalue | Timestamp
4  | abc4        | 2011-10-10
5  | abc5        | 2011-10-11
```

Table_Archive:

```
ID | stringvalue | Timestamp
1  | abc         | 2011-10-01
2  | abc2        | 2011-10-02
3  | abc3        | 2011-10-05
```

And when new input comes into tableA it wont be any problems with ID (PK) in the next move?

What Ive got:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE clean_tables ()
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE _now DATETIME;
    SET _now := NOW();

    INSERT
    INTO    Table_Archive
    SELECT  *
    FROM    TableA
    WHERE   timestamp < _now - 3;
    FOR UPDATE;

    DELETE
    FROM    TableA
    WHERE   timestamp < _now - 3;

    COMMIT;
END
```

How do I change _now to be the date 3 days ago?

Comment: Something wrong with a simple `INSERT` and `DELETE`, running under a cron job?

Comment: I dont know if the ID's will interfere in the future. If I delete from TableA and then makes alot of inserts, won't the ID be used again. And the next move will try to insert a row with the same ID's

Comment: Use a [Sequence](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm) for IDs and it ensures that the IDs will not be repeated.

Comment: @Linqan: No. Your `AUTO_INCREMENT` will continue to behave as if you had not deleted anything (though the `UNIQUE` index on those archived IDs _will_ be lost). Do you really need to preserve the IDs? That seems like a poor design.

Comment: @Manoj: You're skimming over some complexities here.

Comment: No I dont need to save the ID.. So thats's solved.. The last thing now is the get the date 3 days from today at line: SET _now := NOW();

Comment: SET _now := NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY. I've posted up an answer with some more details.

Answer (score 12):

Personally, I would make use of the [MySQL Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html). This is a built in event scheduler rather like CRON in Linux.

You can specify it to call a procedure, procedures or functions or run a bit of SQL at designated intervals.

Read the MySQL docs but an example would be:

```
CREATE EVENT mydatabase.myevent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 WEEK STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
DO
 call clean_tables();
```

So this is saying "call clean_tables() once a week and make the first call in 10 minutes' time"

One gotcha is that the event scheduler is (I think) disabled by default. To turn it on run:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

You can then run:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

To see whether the event scheduler thread is running.

As for preserving your Table A ID column (if you must). I would keep the ID on Table_Archive as unique to that table i.e make it the primary key & auto_increment and then have a 'Original_TableA_ID' column in which to store the TableA ID. You can put a unique index on this if you want.

So Table_Archive would be like:

```
create table `Table_Archive` (
ID int unsigned primary key auto_increment, -- < primary key auto increment
tableAId unsigned int not null, -- < id column from TableA
stringValue varchar(100),
timestamp datetime,
UNIQUE KEY `archiveUidx1` (`tableAId`) -- < maintain uniqueness of TableA.ID column in Archive table
);
```

Nobody seems to have answered your original question "How do I change _now to be the date 3 days ago?". You do that using `INTERVAL`:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE clean_tables ()
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE _now DATETIME;
SET _now := NOW();

INSERT
INTO    Table_Archive
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA
WHERE   timestamp < _now - interval 3 day;
FOR UPDATE;

DELETE
FROM    TableA
WHERE   timestamp < _now - interval 3 day;

COMMIT;
END$

DELIMITER ;
```

One final point is that you should consider creating an index on the timestamp column on TableA to improve the performance of you clean_tables() procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to have a look into `cron jobs` if you want that script/query to be executed automatically.

If you are using `cpanel` have a look into http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron_jobs.htm

Comment: Yes, I thought of cron task, but I wonder if there is anything built in into mysql aswell?

Comment: No, I don't think `MySQL` can automate execution of any query. It will simply run it when its put forwarded. There needs to be someone/program/cronjob that push the query once in a week, in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the best answer (imo) by Tom Mac regarding the event scheduler - be aware that when backing up the schema, you have to specify that you want the events backed up with it via the --events=TRUE flag.

If you're exporting manually in the workbench, the latest version has a checkbox on the main 'Export To Disk' tab - older versions hide it away in the Advanced Export Options tab.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, MySQL will execute query automatically at specific time using MySQL Event Scheduler. Check this link for more details.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html