# MySQL Query Performance with Date Range and Time Step

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table with the following columns: `incident_id`, `creation_date`, `event_id`, `signature_id`.

And this subroutine (simplified version) queries the table:

```
while time1 < end_date and time2 < end_date do
  stmt = "SELECT incident_id, COUNT(event_id) AS total
       FROM table
       WHERE creation_date BETWEEN #{time1} AND #{time2}
         AND signature_id IN (29476,9935,16353,35726,40340,45471,36047,
                              105630,105730,73274)
       GROUP BY signature_id "
  results = db_connect.fetch_all(stmt)
  foreach result in results do
     ... some post processing ...
  end 
  time1 = time1 + time_step
  time2 = time2 + time_step
end
```

The problem with this is that the columns are unindexed and the number of rows is large, so the performances is now really bad. Is there way to do the query without fetching the results inside the loop ?

UPDATE : I figure I should precalculate the time ranges in the loop first, and then do a OR in the SQL query with all of them. The only problem is the COUNT(event_id), I don't know how to calculate it for each time range.

Answer (score 0):

Add this composite index:

```
INDEX(signature_id, creation_date)
```

You could gather all the data in a single query.  Is that what you are looking for?  If so, then you need something like

```
GROUP BY signature_id, some_function(creation_date)
```

The idea behind `some_function` is to take the time, divide by time_step, and use that for grouping.  If it is something simple, like `DAY`, then `LEFT(creation_date, 10)` or `DATE(creation_date)` is simple.  Otherwise, please elaborate on your use case.

Comment: The question mentions a complete lack of indexing though so presumably the OP is at least aware that adding indices should help but hasn't done so for some other reason.

Comment: Based on that, I would assume they're actually looking for something like [archiving](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724824/move-rows-from-tablea-into-table-archive) or put new rows into some 'unprocessed' table first. Optionally combine the two tables in a view to make it appear seamless (but I don't know enough about their situation to form this into a full answer).

Comment: @LukeBriggs - feel free to provide an Answer based you your thoughts.

Comment: Can't use indexes, is a company issue, they want to optimize this without doing that.

Comment: Warm up your resume.  If the company does not let you do your job, but has some lame argument against indexes, get out of there !